# Riak - Python script to load key-value data into Riak buckets

Tags: python, riak, bucket

I have no prior experience with Riak and I am just starting to work on it.

I have data that I would like to load into Riak buckets. For that, I first need to create buckets on the Riak cluster. Are there any example scripts (preferably, in Python) out there that I can refer to do all this - creating buckets + loading data? I did a quick Google search but could not find anything specific.

Any hints/info that can guide me would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't the right place to post this:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

If you have a specific problem and sample code we would be able to help, but try looking at the documentation
https://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/taste-of-riak/python/

Comment: http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/basics/#Writing-Objects click on 'Python'. More detailed info http://basho.github.io/riak-python-client/index.html. Strictly speaking you do not create buckets in Riak because they are just namespaces. You can assume that a bucket already exists when you write to it or change its properties (if other than default).

Comment: Also, as Riak is masterless, writing to a single node means writing to the entire cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend walking through the [Zombie Riak app](http://bit.ly/zombie-demo). The application stack is forked from [this inverted index code](https://github.com/drewkerrigan/riak-inverted-index-demo) written in Ruby, which isn't a big leap to Python. Some notes:

- `riak_hosts.rb` shows how it connects to the Riak KV cluster
- `load_data.rb` is a simple loading process with regular updates
- `models/zombie.rb` shows you the schema